# HorizontalPager with LazyColumn inside another LazyColumn - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I want a similiar effect to TikToks profile screen.
On top is the `ProfilPicture` and `username`, below that is a `stickyHeader` with a `TabRow` (`Posts`, `Drafts`, `Likes`, `Favorites`) and below that is a `HorizontalPager` with the 4 Screens (`Posts`, `Drafts`, `Likes`, `Favorites`), each of these screens contain a list.

If I build this in Compose I get a crash because I cannot nest two `LazyColumns` inside each other.

Here is a short version of what I try to do:

```
val tabList = listOf("Posts", "Drafts", "Likes", "Favorites")
val pagerState: PagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    item {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            //Profile Header (Picture, Username, Followers, etc)
            Text(text = "Profile Picture")
        }
    }

    stickyHeader {
        TabRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            backgroundColor = Color.Black,
            contentColor = Color.White,
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
                )
            }
        ) {
            // Add tabs for all of our pages
            tabList.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    text = { Text(title) },
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    },
                )
            }
        }
    }
    item {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            count = tabList.size
        ) { page: Int ->
            when (page) {
                0 -> PostsList()
                1 -> DraftsList()
                2 -> LikesList()
                else -> FavoritesList()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and inside the `PostList()` composable for example is:

```
@Composable
fun PostList(){
    LazyColumn() {
        items(50){ index ->
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(text = "Button $index")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the crash I get:

```
Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.
```

**EDIT:**
Giving the child `LazyColumn` a fixed height prevents the app from crashing but is not a very satisfying solution.
When the 4 Lists in the `HorizontalPager` have different sizes it gives a weird and buggy behaviour and just doesnt look right.
Another thing that I tried was to use `FlowRow` instead of `LazyColumn`, this also seemed to work and fixed the crash but also here I get a weird behaviour, the Lists in `HorizontalPager` are scrolling synchonously at the same time, which is not what I want.

The `HorizontalPager` is what makes this task so difficult, without it is not a problem at all.

Here is the test project: https://github.com/DaFaack/TikTokScrollBehaviourCompose

This is how it looks like when I give the `LazyColumn` a fixed height of `2500.dp`, only with such a large height it gives the desired scroll behaviour.
The downside here is that even if the List is empty it has a height of 2500 and that causes a bad user experience because it allows the user to scroll even though the list is empty

[image]

Comment: check out [this video section](https://youtu.be/1ANt65eoNhQ?t=899) for reasons and possible solutions

Comment: @PylypDukhov Thanks, I edited my answer and explained why setting a fixed height is not working in this case

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case, using a scrollable `Column` instead of `LazyColumn` in the outer level is easier.

This should achieve what you want:

```
package com.fujigames.nestedscrolltest

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollSource
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.fujigames.nestedscrolltest.ui.theme.NestedScrollTestTheme
import com.google.accompanist.flowlayout.FlowRow
import com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi
import com.google.accompanist.pager.HorizontalPager
import com.google.accompanist.pager.pagerTabIndicatorOffset
import com.google.accompanist.pager.rememberPagerState
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NestedScrollTestTheme {
                BoxWithConstraints {
                    val screenHeight = maxHeight
                    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(200.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .background(Color.LightGray), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "HEADER")
                        }

                        Column(modifier = Modifier.height(screenHeight)) {
                            val tabList = listOf("Tab1", "Tab2")
                            val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
                            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                            TabRow(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                                contentColor = Color.Black,
                                selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                                // Override the indicator, using the provided pagerTabIndicatorOffset modifier
                                indicator = { tabPositions ->
                                    TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                                        Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
                                    )
                                }
                            ) {
                                tabList.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                                    Tab(
                                        text = { Text(title) },
                                        selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                                        onClick = {
                                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                            }
                                        },
                                    )
                                }
                            }

                            HorizontalPager(
                                state = pagerState,
                                count = tabList.size,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxHeight()
                                    .nestedScroll(remember {
                                        object : NestedScrollConnection {
                                            override fun onPreScroll(
                                                available: Offset,
                                                source: NestedScrollSource
                                            ): Offset {
                                                return if (available.y > 0) Offset.Zero else Offset(
                                                    x = 0f,
                                                    y = -scrollState.dispatchRawDelta(-available.y)
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                            ) { page: Int ->
                                when (page) {
                                    0 -> ListLazyColumn(50)
                                    1 -> ListFlowRow(5)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListLazyColumn(items: Int) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(items) { index ->
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button $index")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListFlowRow(items: Int) {
    FlowRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        repeat(items) { index ->
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button $index")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. This is a really clean solution and works as expected.
Is it possible to keep the header above the first item?
So the header should only pop up when the user scrolled back all the way to the top. (like in the gif I posted in my question).

Comment: @HavanaSun I've updated the code. Generally this kind of behaviors can be achieved by custom `NestedScrollConnection`s.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much. I was so close to giving up and not using a HorizontalPager.
I found the documentation to netstedScollConnections pretty hard to understand.
I will give you the bounty reward in 6h

Comment: This is actually a clean implementation, But if while scrolling up , i want the Header text also to slide to Topbar and when scrolling down , should hide the header text from topbar. Please suggest how to acheive it.

Comment: Is there a way where we can imeplement  `rememberLazyListState()` instead `rememberScrollState()`  in first Column, because I want to get some methods like first item offset?

Comment: this works great. where is the `Row` in the outer level though? i just see `Column`s

Comment: @ono Yeah I meant `Column`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Just a minor gripe, as the HorizontalPager swipes there's a large delay before the LazyColumn can be interacted with again. Any way to either minimize this delay or enable intercept swiping on the LazyColumn?

Comment: @6rchid I believe that has been fixed in 1.7.0-alpha03 by [this CL](https://android-review.googlesource.com/2957875).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried 1.7.0-alpha03 but the problem still persists. No difference in 1.7.0-alpha05 as well

Comment: @6rchid In that case please start a new question with a detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Simple impemation of that behavior with **Material3**

1. <s>Go to `build.gradle` and import accompanist pager</s>
   **Since Compose 1.4 Pager is part of Compose foundation**
2. Create PagerScreen with `PagerState`, `CoroutineScope`, `ScrollBehavior`, `TabRow` and `HorizontalPager`, you can use different `scrolBehaviors` provided by `TopAppBarDefaults` or implement your custom `ScrollBehavior`:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerScreen() {
    // Tabs for pager
    val tabData = listOf(
        "Tab 1",
        "Tab 2",
    )

    // Pager state
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    // Coroutine scope for scroll pager
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Scroll behavior for TopAppBar
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Top app bar")
                },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                    scrolledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                ),
            )
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                content = {
                    TabRow(
                        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                        tabs = {
                            tabData.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                                Tab(
                                    text = { Text(title) },
                                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                                    onClick = {
                                        coroutineScope.launch {
                                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                        }
                                    },
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )

                    HorizontalPager(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        pageCount = tabData.size,
                        state = pagerState,
                    ) { tabId ->
                        when (tabId) {
                            0 -> Tab1(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
                            1 -> Tab2(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

3. Create tabs for `HorizontalPager`:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Tab1(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior) {
    // List items
    val listItems = listOf(
        "test 1 tab 1",
        "test 2 tab 1",
        "test 3 tab 1",
        "test 4 tab 1",
        "test 5 tab 1",
        "test 6 tab 1",
        "test 7 tab 1",
        "test 8 tab 1",
        "test 9 tab 1",
        "test 10 tab 1",
        "test 11 tab 1",
        "test 12 tab 1",
    )

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        content = {
            items(items = listItems) { item ->
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),

                    content = { Text(text = item) }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Tab2(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior) {
    // List items
    val listItems = listOf(
        "test 1 tab 2",
        "test 2 tab 2",
        "test 3 tab 2",
        "test 4 tab 2",
        "test 5 tab 2",
        "test 6 tab 2",
        "test 7 tab 2",
        "test 8 tab 2",
        "test 9 tab 2",
        "test 10 tab 2",
        "test 11 tab 2",
        "test 12 tab 2",
    )

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        content = {
            items(items = listItems) { item ->
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),

                    content = { Text(text = item) }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Full code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.andreirozov.pager.ui.theme.PagerTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PagerTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    PagerScreen()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun PagerScreen() {
    // Tabs for pager
    val tabData = listOf(
        "Tab 1",
        "Tab 2",
    )

    // Pager state
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    // Coroutine scope for scroll pager
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Scroll behavior for TopAppBar
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Top app bar")
                },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                    scrolledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                ),
            )
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                content = {
                    TabRow(
                        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                        tabs = {
                            tabData.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                                Tab(
                                    text = { Text(title) },
                                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                                    onClick = {
                                        coroutineScope.launch {
                                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                        }
                                    },
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )

                    HorizontalPager(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        count = tabData.size,
                        state = pagerState,
                    ) { tabId ->
                        when (tabId) {
                            0 -> Tab1(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
                            1 -> Tab2(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Tab1(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior) {
    // List items
    val listItems = listOf(
        "test 1 tab 1",
        "test 2 tab 1",
        "test 3 tab 1",
        "test 4 tab 1",
        "test 5 tab 1",
        "test 6 tab 1",
        "test 7 tab 1",
        "test 8 tab 1",
        "test 9 tab 1",
        "test 10 tab 1",
        "test 11 tab 1",
        "test 12 tab 1",
    )

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        content = {
            items(items = listItems) { item ->
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),

                    content = { Text(text = item) }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Tab2(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior) {
    // List items
    val listItems = listOf(
        "test 1 tab 2",
        "test 2 tab 2",
        "test 3 tab 2",
        "test 4 tab 2",
        "test 5 tab 2",
        "test 6 tab 2",
        "test 7 tab 2",
        "test 8 tab 2",
        "test 9 tab 2",
        "test 10 tab 2",
        "test 11 tab 2",
        "test 12 tab 2",
    )

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        content = {
            items(items = listItems) { item ->
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),

                    content = { Text(text = item) }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]