# How to center image that inside Collapsing Toolbar and Horizontal Pager 's child composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there a way or any method to get the Collapsing + Horizontal pager 's child composable visible height. I need to set empty state inside the child composable, but it's already with fill height, so when I set the empty state, it is not center while the bottom part is invisible at that moment.Thinking the ways:

- to get the visible height and calculate for center and set empty
  state
- if it's related with scrolling behaviour , is there any api or method to handle.

[image]

I would like to center `Empty State` while Collapsing Toolbar is in expanded state.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraints
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ExperimentalLayoutApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FlowRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Tab
import androidx.compose.material.TabRow
import androidx.compose.material.TabRowDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollSource
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi
import com.google.accompanist.pager.pagerTabIndicatorOffset
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


// ref from :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72329873/2772552

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun CenterViewScreen() {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val screenHeight = maxHeight
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState),
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.LightGray),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                Text(text = "HEADER")
            }

            Column(modifier = Modifier.height(screenHeight)) {
                val tabList = listOf("Tab1", "Tab2")
                val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
                val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                TabRow(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    contentColor = Color.Black,
                    selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                    // Override the indicator, using the provided pagerTabIndicatorOffset modifier
                    indicator = { tabPositions ->
                        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                            Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions),
                        )
                    },
                ) {
                    tabList.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                        Tab(
                            text = { Text(title) },
                            selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                            onClick = {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                }
                            },
                        )
                    }
                }

                HorizontalPager(
                    state = pagerState,
                    pageCount = tabList.size,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .nestedScroll(
                            remember {
                                object : NestedScrollConnection {
                                    override fun onPreScroll(
                                        available: Offset,
                                        source: NestedScrollSource,
                                    ): Offset {
                                        return if (available.y > 0) {
                                            Offset.Zero
                                        } else {
                                            Offset(
                                                x = 0f,
                                                y = -scrollState.dispatchRawDelta(-available.y),
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        ),
                ) { page: Int ->
                    when (page) {
                        0 -> ListLazyColumn(0)
                        1 -> ListFlowRow(5)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListLazyColumn(itemsCount: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        if (itemsCount > 0) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                items(itemsCount) { index ->
                    Button(
                        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Button $index")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Column(
                Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.e_commerce_01),
                    contentDescription = "empty state",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(120.dp),
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Centering Empty State",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                    ),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class, ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun ListFlowRow(items: Int) {
    FlowRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        repeat(items) { index ->
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button $index")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Modifier.onPlaced{} and LayoutCoordinates of first parent using layoutCoordinates.parentLayoutCoordiniates, not parentCoordinates, and grand parent which is outer Column in this case and using some math to calculate offset whenever position of parent changes in root.

```
Column(
    Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        .onPlaced { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->
            val contentHeight = layoutCoordinates.size.height

            // This is Box that contains ListLazyColumn or Column
            val parent = layoutCoordinates.parentLayoutCoordinates
            // This is outer Column
            val root = parent?.parentLayoutCoordinates?.parentLayoutCoordinates
            if (parent != null && root != null) {

                val rootHeight = root.size.height
                val parentHeight = parent.size.height
                val parentPosition = parent.positionInRoot().y

                val tabHeight = rootHeight - parentHeight

                offsetY =
                    ((parentHeight - rootHeight - tabHeight - parentPosition + contentHeight) / 2).toInt()

                println(
                    "parent height: ${parentHeight}, " +
                            "parent pos: $parentPosition " +
                            "root height: ${rootHeight}, " +
                            "contentHeight: $contentHeight, " +
                            "tabHeight: $tabHeight, " +
                            "offsetY: $offsetY"
                )
            }

        }
        .offset {
            IntOffset(0, offsetY)
        },
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
) {
    Image(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
        contentDescription = "empty state",
        modifier = Modifier.size(120.dp),
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Blue)
    )
    Text(
        text = "Centering Empty State",
        style = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 18.sp,
        ),
    )
}
```

Result

[image]

Full Demo

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun CenterViewScreen() {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val screenHeight = maxHeight
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState),
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.LightGray),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.drawer_bg2),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                )
            }


            Column(modifier = Modifier.height(screenHeight)) {
                val tabList = listOf("Tab1", "Tab2")
                val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
                    initialPage = 0,
                    initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
                ) {
                    tabList.size
                }
                val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()


                TabRow(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    contentColor = Color.Black,
                    selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage
                ) {
                    tabList.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                        Tab(
                            text = { Text(title) },
                            selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                            onClick = {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                }
                            },
                        )
                    }
                }

                HorizontalPager(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .nestedScroll(
                            remember {
                                object : NestedScrollConnection {
                                    override fun onPreScroll(
                                        available: Offset,
                                        source: NestedScrollSource,
                                    ): Offset {
                                        return if (available.y > 0) {
                                            Offset.Zero
                                        } else {
                                            Offset(
                                                x = 0f,
                                                y = -scrollState.dispatchRawDelta(-available.y),
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        ),
                    state = pagerState,
                    pageSpacing = 0.dp,
                    userScrollEnabled = true,
                    reverseLayout = false,
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
                    beyondBoundsPageCount = 0,
                    pageSize = PageSize.Fill,
                    flingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(state = pagerState),
                    key = null,
                    pageNestedScrollConnection = PagerDefaults.pageNestedScrollConnection(
                        Orientation.Horizontal
                    ),
                    pageContent = { page ->
                        when (page) {
                            0 -> ListLazyColumn(0)
                            1 -> ListFlowRow(5)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListLazyColumn(itemsCount: Int) {

    var offsetY by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        if (itemsCount > 0) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                items(itemsCount) { index ->
                    Button(
                        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Button $index")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Column(
                Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    .onPlaced { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->
                        val contentHeight = layoutCoordinates.size.height

            // This is Box that contains ListLazyColumn or Column
                        val parent = layoutCoordinates.parentLayoutCoordinates
                        // This is outer Column
                        val root = parent?.parentLayoutCoordinates?.parentLayoutCoordinates
                        if (parent != null && root != null) {

                            val rootHeight = root.size.height
                            val parentHeight = parent.size.height
                            val parentPosition = parent.positionInRoot().y

                            val tabHeight = rootHeight - parentHeight

                            offsetY =
                                ((parentHeight - rootHeight - tabHeight - parentPosition + contentHeight) / 2).toInt()

                            println(
                                "parent height: ${parentHeight}, " +
                                        "parent pos: $parentPosition " +
                                        "root height: ${rootHeight}, " +
                                        "contentHeight: $contentHeight, " +
                                        "tabHeight: $tabHeight, " +
                                        "offsetY: $offsetY"
                            )
                        }

                    }
                    .offset {
                        IntOffset(0, offsetY)
                    },
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                Image(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                    contentDescription = "empty state",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(120.dp),
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Blue)
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Centering Empty State",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                    ),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class, ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun ListFlowRow(items: Int) {
    FlowRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        repeat(items) { index ->
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button $index")
            }
        }
    }
}
```